# Automated google search for a number of strings in a given .txt file

Tags: linux, html, search, gwt, automation

I have a list of strings, which I want to search on google independently and get the first link that appears on the search. Also I wanted to search these link's source code for a particular text.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: use either api or use selenium..i am not so sure but it may help